# Does a bow count as a thrown weapon?

Tags: south-park-the-stick-of-truth

I have monk robes on and want to utilize the heal 50 Health Points with a thrown weapon. But I'm not too sure which ones count as thrown and my best weapon I own is a bow. Does a bow count as a thrown weapon or is it only a ranged?

Comment: It's probably only ranged. A thrown weapon would be more like the basketball or throwing knives. If in doubt, you can always equip the robes, initiate combat, then see if it works.

Comment: Thanks! I'll be sure to pay attention to the stats in battle. :)

Answer (score 2):

A bow is a ranged item. Other weapons like throwing knifes and basketballs are thrown weapons.